# External HDD folder close auto in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04

In ubuntu 16.04 when I open external HDD folder in nautilus,

If I go to other applications like firefox or anywhere ... When I came back, I can't see External HDD folder opened in nautilus any more and I should open it again.

But other local folders in nautilus that are not from external devices still open in nautilus and work fine

Just external devices need to be opened again in nautilus

Comment: I don't understand your question well. Is it that your drive is not showing up when trying to download files or explore the drive? Did you make sure that it is mounted correctly?

Comment: I edit my post please review

Comment: So Nautilus is closing by itself? Are you 100% sure that your drive doesn't have connectivity problems OR you are accidentally closing the folder? You could also try another file manager, like Dolphin.

Comment: Yes I check so many times, This is not problem of my external devices or usb, When I load another partition It will be close like external devices

Comment: It is most likely a drive or enclosure problem. Nautilus shouldn't close unless the drive is unmounting itself. In that case, your drive, or USB enclosure, is messed up.

Comment: No Its not drive problem, I told you before If I mount another partition also Nautilus close this folder